# Is there a variable i can query to find out if a feature was selected for installation in the FeaturesDlg

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am using a custom deviation from WixUI_Advanced which uses the FeaturesDlg to choose what components will be installed. One of the components requires a Custom Action for its installation, but I do not want to run that Custom Action if I am not installing that feature. Is there some way to query the installer session or something and build a condition for my Custom Action so that it only fires if this feature has been selected?

**Edit:** I should clarify that I'm looking for language that I can use in a .wxs to determine if the feature has been selected. Something like this, only real code that I didn't make up:

```
      <!--NOT REAL CODE-->
  <Custom Action="ThingToDoIfFeatureSelected"  Before="InstallFinalize">
    $(sys.MyFeatureSessionInformation.Level) > 1
  </Custom>
```

I know this information must exist in the session at run-time, or the installer wouldn't be able to install the correct features, but I cannot find any reference to WIX language that references this session info. I cannot change the code in the Custom Action itself, so I need to test this condition in the WIX markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer. The markup I needed for the condition was this:

```
<Custom Action="ThingToDoIfFeatureSelected"  Before="InstallFinalize">
  <![CDATA[ADDLOCAL >< "MyFeatureName"]]>
</Custom>
```

The global variable ADDLOCAL holds a list of the features which will be installed locally. It is a simple comma separated string, so the `><` operator, which tests if the first string contains the second string, will return true if my feature is in the list. The CDATA prevents me from having to escape the `><`. Without it, `><` has to be written as `&gt;&lt;`

In my case, I have already limited the installation to local by adding this attribute to my feature: `InstallDefault="local"`. So if my feature isn't in ADDLOCAL, it isn't being installed. If I hadn't limited the installation location, I would have to check every possible location, like this:

```
<Custom Action="ThingToDoIfFeatureSelected"  Before="InstallFinalize">
  <![CDATA[ADDLOCAL >< "MyFeatureName" OR ADDSOURCE >< "MyFeatureName" OR ADDDEFAULT >< "MyFeatureName"]]>
</Custom>
```

**Alternate Solution:** I found another simpler and more exact solution for my scenario which checks the "feature-action". The condition `&MyFeatureName=3` means that this is the specific time when we are going to install this feature (it is not installed yet, and we are doing that installation now.) Likewise, the condition `MyFeatureName=2` means that this is when we will uninstall this feature (it is installed now, and we are removing it).

More information on these conditions on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the conditional statements regarding the Feature- or Component-state as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This way you should be able to check if a Feature has been selected for installation or not.